# How to make two break ines in android string resource?

Tags: android, string

I am trying to leave an empty line in a string resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">"Hello\nWorld!"</string>
</resources>
```

The above just puts "world" in the next line, but I need to leave an empty line. any help or sugestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">"Hello\n\nWorld!"</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but did not work. I am calling it txview.setText((context.getResources().getString(R.string.text))) but I do not get any changes

Comment: The name of the string is title not text